# TCP/IP Header Flags

Tags: networking, tcp

In TCP Connection, flags are used to indicate a particular state of connection or to provide some additional useful information like troubleshooting purpose or to handle a control of a particular connection.

There are six TCP flags which we can use in the TCP Header

But my question is can we set Multiple flags in TCP Headers at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can and do!
A normal TCP connection starts with:

```
A: SYN
B: SYN ACK
A: ACK
```

The message by B has both the SYN and the ACK flag set. Each flag takes a single bit so its easy to set multiple

Comment: There are, of course, some flag combinations that do not make sense.

Comment: Given that TCP has 6 flags, with 64 combinations that is not surprising but still good to know

Comment: FYI, every segment past the first SYN has ACK flag set.